# Can jquery proxy be used to avoid closure memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I was reading Google's Javascript style guide regarding closure (http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Closures) and I wonder whether it is safe to use jquery proxy to execute a callback while not fall into the memory leak trap?

Comment: Which memory leak are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember about closures in any managed memory environment is how the garbage collector works. It starts with root objects like "window" and follows every possible memory reference. If it can find an object, then that object can't be reclaimed.

The key is to cut all possible paths when you no longer need the closure. That includes the closure-referencing function, all objects that reference the function, and the object that owns the function. That would include any proxies; null out references to those as well.